# How to fix org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator INFO: unsupported/disabled operation error?

Tags: java, linux, solaris

I wrote a silent printer application using JAVA to print PDF files. This program working fine in window OS  but when i run the same program in solaris OS. When run the same program, I got below error message. I trying to print PostScript printer.

I'm using pdfbox 1.8.0 and my application is returning this error

```
org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: i
```

read the PDF file

```
PDDocument document = getPDFDoc(new File("generated3.pdf"));
```

Many Thanks..

Comment: I don't think Solaris supports PostScript drivers that are needed to print the PDF.

Comment: well if i use the DocPrintJob i can printer PDF in Solaris. but i can't give the page range, i cant print the document like print page 5 to page 10. application print  from the 1st page :(

Comment: You will need to find an alternative to it. Post it as a separate question and wait for answers. Kindly accept the answer if you came to know the cause of the problem.

Comment: well. i wonder is some things wrong with PDFBox...

Comment: I dont think so. If you don't have drivers that are needed to print, you simply can't print.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, **Adobe doesn't offer PostScript drivers for Solaris OS**. They only offer drivers `for Windows and Macintosh platform`. that is required to run the print job. This is why you are getting the exception.

Comment: If so how to print a PDF in PostScript drivers for Solaris OS. i feel if we can covert PDF to PS it may help me to solve my problem. any of you know how to convert PDF to PS

Comment: Post it as a separate question.